# sending parameters to a function in cpp

Tags: c++, function

Is it possible to have a call for a function like this:

```
test({22,11});
```

and then decode the parameter (and their type) in the function declaration? for example:

```
void test(int *a){...}
```

Comment: What do you mean by decode the parameter.? The arguments can be passed as a list. Google passing list as parameters in CPP.

Comment: Your question is somewhat nebulous, and it is unclear what you're trying to do. I suspect [**something like this**](http://ideone.com/feYucl), but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @WhozCraig great pointer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with "decode the parameter", but you can certanly have `test({22,11});`.

```
#include <initializer_list>

void test( std::initializer_list<int> params )
{
    for (int i : params) std::cout << i << ' ';
}
```

Comment: and if I pass double, I should then make sure I have an initializer for test with double defined somewhere?

Comment: @user3639557 Yes. You could also make `test` a template-.

Comment: and this initialization can happen in a separate header file as long as things are being included when they are necessary. Is there a technical name for passing parameters like this and writing such initializers?

Comment: Hm, technical name? I'd call it *a function that takes std::initializer_list.* :)

Comment: Indeed I needed to use it as a template. based on your comment I could find this good ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/

Comment: A quick question: why can't I do this: std::initializer_list<int> param = {22,11} . and then pass it to test as: test(param); ?

Comment: @user3639557 You can do that.